# Different query in the where section, how to transform into 1 query?

Tags: sql, union

I have two simple queries

```
select sum(deb)-sum(cre) as result1 from CXC where id='22731999' 

select sum(deb)-sum(cre) as result2 from CXC where id='22731999' and tipo='IM'
```

the difference is the where, for example the first query results in 769686 and the second in 3469, what I have to do, to see the result of the two queries in one result?

```
result1  result2
----------------
769686   3469
```

I tried

```
select sum(C.deb)-sum(C.cre) as Result1 from CXC C where C.id='22731999'
UNION
select sum(X.deb)-sum(X.cre) as Result2 from CXC X where X.id='22731999' and .tipo='IM'
```

but this is not what I want because it results in 2 rows

```
result1
result2
```

I must say that I used this query under an ODBC bridge to connect Cobol files, the driver is tooo old..  so the sql is quite basic.. I have this limitation :(

the name of the driver is Relational DataBridge for RM Cobol

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
SELECT SUM(t.deb) - SUM(t.cre) as result1,
       (SELECT SUM(x.deb) - SUM(x.cre) 
          FROM CXC x
         WHERE x.id = t.id
           AND x.tipo = 'IM') AS result2
  FROM CXC t
 WHERE t.id = '22731999'
```

...to get:

```
result1  result2
----------------
769686   3469
```

Answer (score 1):

I think of it like this...
union puts queries on top of each other.
joins put queries next to each other.

What I do in this situation is this...

```
SELECT result1, result2 FROM
  (select sum(deb)-sum(cre) as result1, id from CXC where id='22731999' ) query1
JOIN
(select sum(deb)-sum(cre) as result2, id from CXC where id='22731999' and tipo='IM') query2
 ON query1.id = query2.id
```

To simplify what's going on here, just pretend that query1 is a table, and query2 is a table

```
select result1, result2 
from query1
join query2 on query1.id = query2.id
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try a self join.  It would be something like this:

select sum(C.deb)-sum(C.cre) as Result1, sum(X.deb)-sum(X.cre) as Result2
from CXC C, CXC X
where C.id='22731999' and X.id='22731999' and .tipo='IM'

Comment: whell this query doent fails..  but the result is too different.

Comment: probably has a cartesian product.  Might need to add the primary key to the where clause (ex. C.id = X.id)

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

```
SELECT max(Result1) as Result1, max(Result2) as Result2
FROM
    (
    SELECT 
    select sum(C.deb)-sum(C.cre) as Result1, null as Result2
    from CXC C where C.id='22731999'
    UNION
    select null as Result1, sum(X.deb)-sum(X.cre) as Result2 
    from CXC X where X.id='22731999' and .tipo='IM'
    ) x
```